# Regarding C# Jagged array dynamic auto incrementing array array not printing values properly

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic, jagged-arrays

I'm working on auto increment array but this logic is not working properly for jagged arrays:

```
namespace TESETER
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int q, moj = 0;
            int[][] arr = new int[1][];
            int[][] b;
            b = arr;
            arr[0] = new int[1];
            b[0] = arr[0];
            while (moj < 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("interger");
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out q);
                if (moj < 1)
                { arr[0][0] = q; moj++; }
                else
                {
                    moj++; arr[0] = new int[moj];
                    for (int i = 0; i < moj - 1; i++)
                    {
                        arr[0][i] = b[0][i];
                    }
                    arr[0][moj - 1] = q;
                    b = arr;
                    b[0] = arr[0];
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(arr[0][0]);
            Console.WriteLine(arr[0][1]);
            Console.WriteLine(arr[0][2]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Ouput:** integer 7 integer 8 integer 9 009

please help I want output 789 if input is 789

Comment: could you elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve in your algorithm?

Comment: hey i want run time incrementation  of jagged array

Comment: above code limits it to three but if i change  while(moj<3) to while(true) then it should accept  but the problem is it is not printing the expected results

Comment: are you using "b" to keep previous values? Currently it is referring to same object.

Comment: Single integer array of array

Comment: i want to take integer from user assign it to the first array pointed by jagged array if user wants to add another integer to array then that arry should increment its size autoatically then accept do this while user wants and then print it i havent added while true and for loop for display for debugging and simplicity

Comment: yes i am using b to keep track of previous values

Comment: it is printing zeros except last entered  value  but the expected out put is all the three values should be printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use `List<int>` instead of jagged array. It automatically resized when you add new elements to it.

If you have to use jagged array here, do not use assignment to keep previous values. use `Array.Copy` instead.

```
using System;
namespace TESETER
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int q, moj = 0;
        int[][] arr = new int[1][];
        int[][] b = new int[1][];
        // b = arr;
        // arr[0] = new int[1];
        // Array.Copy(arr[0], b[0]);
        while (moj < 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("interger");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out q);
            if (moj < 1)
            { arr[0][0] = q; moj++; }
            else
            {
                moj++; arr[0] = new int[moj];
                for (int i = 0; i < moj - 1; i++)
                {
                    arr[0][i] = b[0][i];
                }
                arr[0][moj - 1] = q;
                Array.Copy(arr, b);
                //b[0] = arr[0];
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(arr[0][0]);
        Console.WriteLine(arr[0][1]);
        Console.WriteLine(arr[0][2]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot you saved a lot of time thanks ! thats what i wanted now it works well

Comment: sorry for bad english